# Pop up box on custom wordpress theme that i want to be visible until user closes it 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the following popup box

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="box">
        <h2 class="top_stories_title forma_title forma_outer">Συμπλήρωσε τα στοιχεία σου για να πάρεις την προσφορά!</h2>
            <div class="popup_image_area">
                <img class="popup_image_main" src="/wp-content/themes/whsk_alpha/common/imgs/energia_image.jpg" alt="fisiki_energeia">
            </div>
            <div class="popup_form">
                <div class="close">&times;</div>
                <!--form-->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have the following js

```
const loginPopup = document.querySelector(".popup");
const close = document.querySelector(".close");

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    showPopup();
})


function showPopup(){
    const timeLimit = 5; // sec
    let y = false;
    let i = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(function(){
        i++;

        if( i == timeLimit && y == false){
            clearInterval(timer);
            loginPopup.classList.add("show");
        }
        console.log(i);
        console.log(y);
    },1000);

}


close.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let y = 0;
    loginPopup.classList.remove("show");
    y = true;

} )
```

that is responsive to make the popup visible after 5 secs and to be closed if the user press close. I want the popup to reappear if the user visits the same page at the same session BUT i want to make it closed forever if the user closes the window the second time it appers. Thats why i use the `y = true;` but am i supposed to tranfer the variable from `close.addEventListener` to `function showPopup()` ?

Comment: Any JS variable will not “live” any longer than the user stays on the current page. If they reload the page, or go to a different page and then come back, your variables won’t exist any more. So the first thing you need to do, is store this counter value somewhere, where you can read it back from. This could either be a server-side session (then you’d have to combine PHP and JS logic here), or you store it on the client side, in sessionStorage.

Comment: i see... thank you